# Need help with wiring of in-line ventilation fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, ventilation

I've got this fan to install as part of a heat transfer system. The fan is controlled by a touch-screen thermostat/control unit and has three speeds.

I understand the supplied wiring diagram, but I'm wondering how best to implement it.

Should I find 4-conductor cable and join the neutral back by the control unit, or run a separate wire for the neutral?

So basically, whats the best way to physically run the wires?

Thanks

[image: supplied diagram]

[image: my idea]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running the wires back to the control unit anyway - I would run 4 wires back to the unit and connect them all including the ground in that location.

This should prevent any issue with ground loops.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my post with my idea how to do it. Will this do suffice?

Comment: None of the conductors diagrammed indicate "ground" anywhere. Your fan should have its own grounding connection, assuming it has any exposed metal parts.

Comment: @Kokako - you should ground it as well - generally your circulation fan in the air handler is attached to the Air Handler unit and therefore it is grounded to the unit - which is most likely grounded with a grounding wire from the main power panel - run the additional ground wire to your fan. Electrical wire labeling leaves much to be desired. The dash_number indicates insulated conductors - something like 10-4 or 12-4 with ground (5 wires) you need to have a ground for that fan. If the neutral opens you have a high risk of electrocution.

Comment: Sorry guys but I misspoke when I used the word "ground" I meant "natural" the fan is double insulated so no ground is needed. How does my wiring plan look to you now?